# JavaFX CSS not working

Tags: css, scala, javafx, scalafx

I am having trouble with this sample not styling the background borderpane green. The css has NO effect at all no matter how much I tweak it.
My code:

StackoverflowQuestion.scala

```
import scalafx.application.JFXApp
import scalafx.application.JFXApp.PrimaryStage
import scalafx.scene.Scene
import scalafx.scene.control.Button
import scalafx.scene.layout.BorderPane

object StackoverflowQuestion extends JFXApp {

   stage = new PrimaryStage {
      title = "Stackoverflow Sample"

      scene = new Scene {
         stylesheets add getClass.getResource("app.css").toExternalForm

         content = new BorderPane {
            id = "background"

            center = new Button {
               text = "Button"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

app.css

```
#background {
    -fx-background-color: green;
}
```

I did see this related post but it has no answer
[JavaFx Css not working with eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24564973/javafx-css-not-working-with-eclipse). I know that the css is being read because it prints a error if I remove a brace from the css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at you original code. The issue is more likely with layout than CSS. The pane is covered by the button so you cannot see it. You need to make sure that pane is larger than the button, for instance, add padding to you CSS:

```
#background {
    -fx-background-color: green;
    -fx-padding: 10;
}
```

Here is what I see when I do that:

[image: Button with padding and green background]

Second thing you may want to do is to change `content` to `root`, so your pane will fill the `Scene`, you will have

```
root = new BorderPane { ...
```

When you use `root` you put a pane directly on the scene. The restriction is that you can only assign a `Parent` to `root` (no problem here). When you use `content` you can assign any `Node` but it is first wrapped into a `Group` before being assigned to `root`. Wrapping in `Group` changes how the layout is done, in your case limiting size of the `BorderPane` to its content rather stretching it to match `Scene` size.

Comment: Ah, thank you. This is exactly what is was looking for. I had no idea that root was the correct way to do that. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

i hope that will help you

```js
package application;

import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class StackOverFlow extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
        primaryStage.setTitle("JavaFX Welcome");
        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
        pane.setId("pane");

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(Welcome.class.getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
        
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

```css
#pane{
 -fx-background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I was looking for more of a "this is why it won't work", but thank you any way. BTW where did  `Welcome.class` come from? Your class is named `StackOverFlow `.

Comment: Welcome it's the name of the project, I forgot to change by the name of the class but it works anyway.

Comment: sorry, i can't help ou more, i don't know scala.

Comment: Well, Thank you any way, looks like I'll be playing around for a while longer

Comment: no soucy, i have the same problem for the reputation, anyway i was thinking to put .root in the css file instead of the id #pane.

Comment: actually.root doesn't style anything https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#scene `"The Scene object has no settable CSS properties"`